# Error calling TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication()

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-rt

I'm playing around with sample code that makes use of live tiles, and when it tries to create the `TileUpdater` instance via:

```
TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication()
```

It immediately crashes with the following message:

```
The notification platform is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E0105)
```

This happens when deploying to both the simulator and the local machine.

*EDIT*

While digging through event logs, I stumbled across a few of these:

```
The Windows Notification platform has failed initialization.  Notifications will not work until after a restart.
```

I've restarted a bunch of of times already though.

Comment: is this a simple app scenario or part of a background task?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean.  It just allows a piece of the data that's normally displayed in the app to be visible as a tile.

Comment: ok, if you don't know what I meant then it's likely not a background task :) (that would have been something you would have explicitly done).  Out of curiosity, does the [sample here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148) also fail?

Comment: If you restart your machine, can you reproduce this error?

Comment: I've restarted a couple times, and it also fails with that other sample application on the same exact API call.

Comment: Are there errors in the following event log?  Applications and Services -> Microsoft -> Windows -> PushNotifications-Platform

Comment: @NathanKuchta the only relevant log I can find I added earlier to my original post.

Comment: Actually, I also found a few verbose messages that are like: `The Windows Push Notification Platform has encountered an error in file: base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\endpoint\platform.cpp, function NotificationPlatform::Initialize, line 574: 0x80072EE4.`

Comment: That particular error indicates that required paths (either %LocalAppData% or %AppData%\Roaming) are inaccessible.  Can you access those directories, or were permissions to those directories modified?  Is the same error encountered when logged in as another user?

Comment: I can get to `%LocalAppData%` but `%AppData%\Roaming` doesn't seem to exist, although `%AppData%` evaluates to `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming`.  Did you mean to append an extra `\Roaming` on the end, or is my env. just messed up somehow?

Comment: I was able to successfully deploy this to an actual remote surface device, so it's only failing on the simulator and local machine :(

Comment: @NathanKuchta I missed your suggestion of trying this as another user... this problem doesn't occur when I use the local administrator account on the machine (I was previously using my domain account, which is an administrator though).  Has to be some kind of permission thing then like you said, just can't figure out what :(

Comment: @chinabuffet - is it possible that your domain controller is making changes to the location of %AppData%\Roaming via group policy? That would be what I'd check, given that it seems to work with a local admin account, and given that it works when deployed to a device.

Comment: @chinabuffet Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue, affecting all apps in my user account.

Comment: @fefrei No, although I stopped tinkering with Windows development shortly after I had this problem (almost 2 years ago now).

Comment: @chinabuffet Too bad. I'm still struggling with a similar problem [here](http://superuser.com/questions/860015/), but I guess I'll give up and create a new profile...